# How can I implement JCE in java for Android?

Tags: android, encryption, jce

I has been request to develop an Android app, this app has to connect to a java server but this have to have with high security. On the server side, it will be implement JCE and I wonder if it is possible to implement JCE in a java Android code or what alternatives do I have to do this? I've read the android API but there is not any info about this...  thanks

Comment: Could you explain a little more on the kind of encryption your trying to achieve i.e RSA, AES?

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK is based on Java and is compliant with the java cryptography extension (JCE). For most of your encryption needs you can use the JCE API without worrying about the underlying cryptographic implementation.